# Создание расширения для VS Code, поиск файла и получение его содержимого

Tags: visual-studio-code, extension, visual-studio-extensions

Пишу расширение(*Language Server Protocol*) для VS Code для поддержки проприетарного языка программирования. Соответственно расширение состоит из двух частей - серверной и клиентской.
В серверной части в процессе парсинга исходника получаю имя файла *"fileName.ext"* и его как-то надо найти и получить его содержимое. В клиентской части нашел
`workspace.findFiles(name);`
но в серверной части это не работает. Подскажите как можно осуществить поиск файла и получить его содержимое, зная его имя в серверной части.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сам спросил, сам ответил. Тот же ответ на англ версии сайта.

On server side:

```
export function GetFileRequest(nameInter:string) {
    connection.sendRequest("getFile", nameInter).then( (body : string) => {
        if (body != undefined && body.length) pushImports(body);
    });
}
```

on client side:
in *function activate(context: ExtensionContext)* after client.start();

```
    client.onReady().then(() => {
        client.onRequest("getFile", (nameInter : string) : Promise<string> => { return getFile(nameInter); } );
    });
```

and async function on client side:

```
async function getFile(name):Promise<string>{
    let uri:Uri = undefined;
    let text:string = undefined;
    await workspace.findFiles(name, null, 1).then((value)=> {
        if (value.length) {
            uri=value[0];
        }
    });
    if (uri!=undefined) {
        let textDocument;
        await workspace.openTextDocument(uri).then((value)=>textDocument = value);
        text = textDocument.getText();
    }
    return text;
}
```

This code will return a text from file to server side.